# Update/change the sort order for existing product attribute using upgrade scripts?

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, adminhtml, product-attribute, sorting

How do i update/change the sort order for existing product attribute using upgrade scripts?

I want to change the order in which the product attributes are listed in the admin. Is there any other way to do that through upgrade scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bellow update scripts

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app('default');

class Attribute
{
    public function index()    
    {    

        $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
        $installer->startSetup(); 
        $installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product','name', array(''),null,2); //entity Type Id, Attribute id or Attribute code, field, value = null, sortOrder = null)
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}

$obj = new Attribute();
$obj->index();
?>
```